# Amp page implementation with same page

Tags: html, seo, shopify, amp-html, google-amp

I'm trying to implement AMP page with shopify. Shopify does not give server side code. It is a hosted solution. So i can not redirect my page from server side unless it gives me 404 error.

Let's suppose I have this product URL

https://securecod3.myshopify.com/products/3-4-baseball-tee

And I want to make AMP page of this product. I can set two different HTML with using '?view' query string.
So, I created another AMP  version of this page using this URL

https://securecod3.myshopify.com/products/3-4-baseball-tee?view=amp

I have two questions.

1. Is this a proper way to use AMP page if you do not have server-side control?
2. I user this code in regular page for amp redirection

   rel="amphtml" href="https://securecod3.myshopify.com/products/3-4-baseball-tee?view=amp"

And this code in AMP page.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://securecod3.myshopify.com/products/3-4-baseball-tee">
```

It will work or I need some changes here. Please guide me here.